# Radio Button Tab Selection via API using Template

Tags: docusignapi

I've got a really strange problem. I have created a template which contains one Radio Button Group (rdoAction) with 3 separate radio buttons (DepositTo, Reissue, Other). When I create my envelope via the API I pass the radio group tab, with the specific radio button I want selected. Here is the strange part, it works perfectly when I pass the information to select either the Reissue or Other radio Button, but when the signing session loads, the DepositTo radio button is never selected.
I tried deleting that radio button from my template and then adding a new one in its place with no luck. I also tried deleting it and then copied and pasted one of the working ones in its place and changed the value accordingly. Using that method got the DepositTo radio button working but broke the one I originally copied.
Also, all of the radio buttons have the same attributes in my template aside from the value and location.

I know I am sending the correct XML down because I use the same function to build the XML for each of the radio buttons. Any ideas on why only 2 of the 3 will work?

UPDATE:
Here is the radio Group Tabs from the GetEnvelopeRecipients:

```
"radioGroupTabs": [
  {
    "documentId": "1",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "groupName": "rdoAction",
    "radios": [
      {
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "72",
        "yPosition": "240",
        "value": "Reissue",
        "selected": "false",
        "tabId": "206e8111-6cf9-4c79-b821-11f6958199c6"
      },
      {
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "74",
        "yPosition": "255",
        "value": "Other",
        "selected": "false",
        "tabId": "9705c14c-964e-4721-8f1b-35e4319794d4"
      },
      {
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "xPosition": "72",
        "yPosition": "221",
        "value": "DepositTo",
        "selected": "false",
        "tabId": "2352005b-d4f1-4be9-9c51-2fef2205739e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my trace for that radio button selection:

```
<TabStatus>
    <TabType>Custom</TabType> 
    <Status>Active</Status> 
    <XPosition>150</XPosition> 
  <YPosition>500</YPosition> 
  <TabLabel>rdoAction</TabLabel> 
  <TabName>Reissue</TabName> 
  <TabValue /> 
  <DocumentID>1</DocumentID> 
  <PageNumber>1</PageNumber> 
  <ValidationPattern /> 
  <CustomTabType>Radio</CustomTabType> 
  </TabStatus>
<TabStatus>
  <TabType>Custom</TabType> 
  <Status>Active</Status> 
  <XPosition>154</XPosition> 
  <YPosition>531</YPosition> 
  <TabLabel>rdoAction</TabLabel> 
  <TabName>Other</TabName> 
  <TabValue /> 
  <DocumentID>1</DocumentID> 
  <PageNumber>1</PageNumber> 
  <ValidationPattern /> 
  <CustomTabType>Radio</CustomTabType> 
  </TabStatus>
<TabStatus>
  <TabType>Custom</TabType> 
  <Status>Active</Status> 
  <XPosition>150</XPosition> 
  <YPosition>460</YPosition> 
  <TabLabel>rdoAction</TabLabel> 
  <TabName>DepositTo</TabName> 
  <TabValue /> 
  <DocumentID>1</DocumentID> 
  <PageNumber>1</PageNumber> 
  <ValidationPattern /> 
  <CustomTabType>Radio</CustomTabType> 
  </TabStatus>
  </TabStatuses>
```

If you need any additional information, let me know and I can provide it.

Here is the XML I send to set the radio button, the value changes based on the radio button selection.
Thanks. Here is the strange thing. I am not setting the tabValue to X for any of the radio buttons. I am sending down the following XML based on the radio button selection:

```
<radioGroupTabs>
<radioGroup>
<groupName>rdoAction</groupName>
<radios>
<radio>
<value>DepositTo</value>
<selected>true</selected>
</radio>
</radios>
</radioGroup>
</radioGroupTabs>
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include: 1) a Trace of the XML request body that you're sending to DocuSign when you see this strange behavior, and 2) the Response from a "GET Recipients" call for the problematic envelope -- GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeID}}/recipients?include_tabs=true

Comment: Added what you requested. After doing that, I noticed that there is an X in the tabValue of my trace for the working radio buttons but not this one. I am sending the tab values the exact same way for each of the radio buttons so now I am stumped as to why the X isn't in the tabValue for DepositTo when I clearly sent selected: true; in my API call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the additional info to your question.

So, your issue (the **DepositTo** radio button not being selected in the Envelope) is most certainly being caused by the fact that the **Create Envelope** XML request you're sending to DocuSign doesn't specify to select that radio button -- i.e., `<TabValue />` element is empty for the **DepositTo** radio button in the request.

If you can get your code to generate an XML request that puts an **X** in the `<TabValue>` element for the **DepositTo** radio button, then DocuSign should select that radio button, just as you specify in the XML request.  Perhaps step through your code in Debug mode to determine why the "X" isn't being added to the request when the **DepositTo** is the button should be selected?

Comment: Thanks. Here is the strange thing... I am not specifically setting the tabValue to X for any of the radio buttons.. I have added the XML I send to set the radio button in my original post.

Another twist to the plot though. I switched to the New DocuSign Experience, deleted my radio button group and added them back. I can't lock the radio buttons from the new experience but all 3 get selected accurately now... So I wonder if there is some sort of bug that I found when attempting to lock a radio button group or I am setting the attributes incorrectly causing the problem.

Comment: Very interesting.  Not sure why the different experience with the 'new DocuSign experience' -- but glad to hear that it's working there.  (PS - When I said "put an X in the <TabValue> element", I didn't necessarily mean that literally -- your code may simply be setting a property on an object that ultimately results in it generating an XML request that has "X" in the <TabValue> element for the radio button you want to select.)

Comment: Another new development. It looks like it might be related to the Conditional Field attached to that radio button. I went back to the old experience and locked the fields in the template and it worked, but as soon as set the text field to be conditional on this radio button it stopped working, so I am going to look at that to make sure I am setting everything accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working as desired. Here is my solution, well actually more of a workaround.

It looks like it wasn't related to the radio buttons but related to the conditional text fields I had attached to the radio button selection. 2 of the 3 radio buttons had text fields that were conditional based on the radio button selection. I could not find anything in my trace that looked out of place, but once I set one of the text fields to be conditional on my DepositTo radio button, the selection would no longer work. So what I did was remove the conditional attributes from the text fields on my template and am now controlling whether I send data down for those text fields in my front end code.

All 3 radio buttons are now being selected accurately and the text fields associated with them are populating data as desired.

Not sure if I found some sort of bug or if I am just not familiar enough with the process to  see what mistake I might have been making in my template. Regardless here is a workaround if you experience the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer